# Improvement of a (working) function to obtain the rows where decimal number has certain number of decimal positions

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have created three test tables: users, teams and membership, which relates users and yeams.
The users table contains a user_id column which is the primary key.
The memberships table contains a user_id foreign key and another column called cost, with a decimal value.

Then I proposed myself the following SQL challenge, based on some interview questions I have read:

> "Write the SQL code needed in order to get users with a cost that has at most N decimal places"

The SQL code must use SQL functions (and I use PostgreSQL).

The actual code I have written is:

```sql
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION GET_NTH_DEC_RESIDUE(NUMERIC, INTEGER) RETURNS NUMERIC AS
    $function$
    SELECT CAST(CAST($1 AS NUMERIC) * POW(10,$2) - FLOOR(CAST($1 AS NUMERIC)*POW(10,$2)) AS NUMERIC);
    $function$
LANGUAGE SQL;

SELECT user_id, cost, nth_pos_dec
FROM (SELECT user_id, GET_NTH_DEC_RESIDUE(CAST(memberships.cost AS NUMERIC), 2) AS nth_pos_dec
      FROM users
        JOIN memberships
        USING (user_id)) AS T
WHERE NOT (nth_pos >= 0.0 AND nth_pos < 1.0);
```

The function `GET_NTH_DEC_RESIDUE` gets the residual decimal number (e.g. for 0.345 and 2 decimal positions, the function returns 0.5, for 0.12345 and 3 decimal positions it returns 0.45). The cost values we are looking for are then those which are not in the range [0,1).

By "applying" the function to the joined users+memberships view, it generates a new column with the residual decimal numbers and the right rows can be chosen.

This solution seems to do the job pretty well, but I am not fully satisfied with it.

I tried to wrap the logical comparison into another SQL function so that the main query gets simplified, but I did not manage to make it.

Is anyone able to devise a more elegant way to do this? (note that I am interested in using SQL functions and I do not want to do string conversions).

Thanks!

Comment: If you're trying to improve performance of the query as a whole, you will want create an indexed column to store the result of the function; so as to avoid doing the math for the entire table every time you want to run the query. Calculations, no matter how small, against a column in the `where` clause is going to drastically increase your cpu usage.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your function is a nice one. Here are some things that I think could be optimized:

1. you don't need to cast the first parameter to `NUMERIC` - it's already of this type, so first optimization could be:

   ```
   CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION GET_NTH_DEC_RESIDUE(NUMERIC, INTEGER) RETURNS NUMERIC AS
       $function$
       SELECT CAST($1 * POW(10, $2) - FLOOR($1 * POW(10, $2)) AS NUMERIC);
       $function$
   LANGUAGE SQL;
   ```
2. when you check the return value of the function, there is no need to check if it is less than 1 - it could never be equal or greater than 1, so you could just check if it's equal to 0 (I've checked that the function works fine with negative values too):

   ```
   ...
   WHERE nth_pos = 0
   ```
3. if you don't need the numeric value returned by this function, you could change it to return `boolean` and use it only in the `WHERE` clause (notice, that you wouldn't need the cast at all):

   ```
   CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION GET_NTH_DEC_RESIDUE(NUMERIC, INTEGER) RETURNS BOOLEAN AS
       $function$
       SELECT $1 * POW(10, $2) - FLOOR($1 * POW(10, $2)) = 0;
       $function$
   LANGUAGE SQL;

   SELECT
           user_id,
           cost
   FROM
           users
           JOIN memberships
           USING (user_id)
   WHERE
           GET_NTH_DEC_RESIDUE(CAST(memberships.cost AS NUMERIC), 2);
   ```
4. you can calculate the `POW(10, $2)` only once (I'm not sure if query planner wouldn't do that anyway):

   ```
   CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION GET_NTH_DEC_RESIDUE(NUMERIC, INTEGER) RETURNS BOOLEAN AS
       $function$
       WITH precalc AS (
           SELECT POW(10, $2) AS power
       )
       SELECT 
           $1 * power - FLOOR($1 * power) = 0
       FROM
           precalc;
       $function$
   LANGUAGE SQL;
   ```

Comment: Thank you so much @Adam. My concern was not speed but style (and the wish to explore SQL limits). Your answer has been extra-helpful.